# Как продлить время выполнения php-скрипта?

Tags: apache, php, linux

У меня есть скрипт и он долго выполняется.
Всего по умолчанию дано 30 сек, об этом говорится в логах.

> [Thu Nov 10 00:07:48 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/xxx/SOM.inc on line 291

Где можно увеличить время выполнения?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возможно, **[set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php)**.

Если поставить в 0, к тому же, ограничение на время выполнения скрипта вообще отсутствует.

Answer (score 5):

В php.ini прописать:

```
max_execution_time = 60
```

Только это не панацея - через 60 сек некоторые броузеры разрывают соединение, и тогда apache прибивает процесс

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй  в php 
   `php ini_set("max_execution_time", "60");` 
    или файл `.htaccess` -> `php_value max_execution_time 60`.

Answer (score 1):

Для увеличения времени работы скрипта, в начале кода пропишите вот это (где цифры это время выполнения скрипта в секундах)

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');
```