# ubuntu error code 255

Tags: php, ubuntu

У меня есть PHP скрипт который всегда весит в безконечном цикле(обработчик Телеграм бота)
Когда я его запускаю в консоле на хостинге (php init.php)
Он какое-то время работает коректно ,но силу не извесных мне обстаятельств
через некоторое время видаёт ошибку 255 и закрывает скрипт.
вот код из init.php
примечание: 
 1.на локалке все хорошо работает.
 2.Хостинг на убунту.

```
<?php 
require 'bot.php';
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server_url.';dbname='.$server_db_name.'', $server_user_name, $server_password);
$bot = new  TelBot;
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
//  echo "1";
    $updates = $bot->getUpdates();
    if(is_array($updates) || is_object($updates)){
foreach ($updates->result as $update) {
    if(!empty($update)){
        $id =  $update->message->chat->id;
        $text = $update->message->text;
        echo $text;
        $comand = explode(' ', substr($text, 1))[0]; 
        $comandParrams = explode(' ', substr($text, 1))[1];
        if(trim($comandParrams) == ''){
            $comandParrams = false;
        }
        //var_dump($comandParrams);
        //echo $comand;
        switch ($comand) {
            case 'start':
            $bot-> sendMessage('Привіт, я робот магазину F5!', $id);
            $bot-> sendMessage('Ось мох команди: 1./find 100xxx - Переглянути статус ремонту (100ххх - код квитанції) 2./restore - Відновити згублену квитанцію 3./help - продивитися всі команди', $id);
                break;
            case 'help':
                $bot-> sendMessage('Ось мох команди: 1./find 100xxx - Переглянути статус ремонту (100ххх - код квитанції) 2./restore - Відновити згублену квитанцію 3./help - продивитися всі команди', $id);
                break;
            case 'find':
            $findID = $comandParrams;
            if($comandParrams == false){
                $bot->sendMessage('Не правильний формат команди', $id);
            }else{
                $res = R::getRow("SELECT `price_our` FROM `remont` WHERE `id_publick` = ".$comandParrams);
                    if(!$res){
                $bot->sendMessage('Ваш телефон не знайдено :/', $id);   
                    }else{
if($res['price_our'] == '' or $res['price_our'] == 'Null'  or $res['price_our'] == ' '){
     $bot->sendMessage('Ваш телефон в ремонті...', $id);
    }else{
        if($res['price_our'] != "не зроб" || $res['price_our'] != "не зроблено" || $res['price_our'] != "не зроб."|| $res['price_our'] != "не зроб"|| $res['price_our'] != "X"|| $res['price_our'] != "x"|| $res['price_our'] != "х"|| $res['price_our'] != "Х"){
                            $bot->sendMessage('Ваш телефон зроблено, ціна: '.$res['price_our'].'грн.', $id);
                        }else{
                            $bot->sendMessage('Ваш телефон не не зроблено', $id);
                        }
    }
                    }
                //$res['price_our']
            }
                    break;
                    case 'restore':
                            $sql = "DELETE FROM `telegram` WHERE `chat_id` = ".$id;
//echo $sql;
                $pdo->query($sql);
                $bot-> sendMessage('Ок, тоді в наступному повідомлені надішліть КОД квитанції. Приклад повідомлення: /id 100xxx', $id);
                $restore = R::dispense('telegram');
                $restore->chatId = $id;
                $restore->id_publick = '';
                $restore->surName = '';
                $restore->phoneNum = '';
                R::store($restore);
                    break;  
                    case 'id':
            $idKvit = $comandParrams;
            if($comandParrams == false){
                $bot->sendMessage('Не правильний формат команди', $id);
            }else{
$sql = "UPDATE `telegram` SET `id_publick` = '".$idKvit."' WHERE `chat_id` = ".$id;
//echo $sql;
$pdo->query($sql);
            $bot->sendMessage('Тепер напишіть ваш номер телефону який ви вказували коли здавали телефон в форматі: /num 0991234567', $id);
            $bot->sendMessage('Також  напишіть ваше прізвище в форматі /surn Крaвчук', $id);}
                    break;
                    case 'num':
    if($comandParrams == false){
                $bot->sendMessage('Не правильний формат команди', $id);
            }else{                  
            $phoneNum = $comandParrams;
            if(strlen($phoneNum) < 10){
                $bot->sendMessage('Замало цифр!', $id);
            }elseif (strlen($phoneNum) > 10) {
                $bot->sendMessage('Забагато цифр!', $id);
            }else{
                $sql = "UPDATE `telegram` SET `phone_num` = '".$phoneNum."' WHERE `chat_id` = ".$id;
//echo $sql;
$pdo->query($sql);
$res = R::getRow("SELECT * FROM `telegram` WHERE `chat_id` = ".$id);
            if($res['sur_name'] == ''){
                $bot->sendMessage('Тепер  напишіть ваше прізвище в форматі /surn Крaвчук', $id);
            }else{
                $bot->sendMessage('Щоб підтвердити налаштування напишіть /exec', $id);
            }

            }
}
                        break;
                        case 'surn':
                if($comandParrams == false){
                $bot->sendMessage('Не правильний формат команди', $id);
            }else{              
$surname = $comandParrams;
                if(strlen($surname) < 6){
            $bot->sendMessage('Замало букв!', $id);
                }else{
            $sql = "UPDATE `telegram` SET `sur_name` = '".$surname."' WHERE `chat_id` = ".$id;
            $res = R::getRow("SELECT * FROM `telegram` WHERE `chat_id` = ".$id);
            if($res['phone_num'] == ''){
                $bot->sendMessage('Тепер  напишіть ваш номер телефону який ви вказували коли здавали телефон в форматі /num 0991234567', $id);
            }else{
                $bot->sendMessage('Щоб підтвердити налаштування напишіть /exec', $id);
            }
//echo $sql;
$pdo->query($sql);
                }
}
                        break;
                        case 'exec':

$bot-> sendMessage('В обробці...', $id);
                        $res = R::getRow("SELECT * FROM `telegram` WHERE `chat_id` = ".$id);
                        if(empty($res)){
                            $bot-> sendMessage('Ви ще не ініцілювали процес створення копії квитанції. Щоб розпочати його напишіть /restore', $id);
                        }else{
                            if($res['phone_num'] == ''){
                                $bot-> sendMessage('Увведіть номер телефону в форматі: /num 0991234567', $id);
                            }else{
                                if($res['sur_name'] == ''){
                                    $bot-> sendMessage('Увведіть ваше прізвище в форматі /surn Крaвчук', $id);
                                }else{
                                    if($res['id_publick'] == ''){
                                        $bot-> sendMessage('У наступному повідомлені надішліть КОД квитанції. Приклад повідомлення: /id 100xxx', $id);  
                                    }else{
                                            $link = 'http://f5remont.beget.tech/bot/envelope.php?id='.$res['chat_id'];
                                        //$link = 'тут буде ссилка';
                                        $bot-> sendMessage($link, $id);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                            break;
            default:
                $bot-> sendMessage('Я вас не розумію...', $id);
                break;
        }
    }
}
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/51834/178576)?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала посмотрите конфигурацию, нет ли там ограничений на время исполнения консольных скриптов: `max_execution_time` в `php.ini`.

Уберите лимит:

`set_time_limit(0);`
или

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Оберните код в `try catch` и пойманные ошибки (при их наличии) пишите в файл, чтобы была возможность отслеживать что же пошло не так, ну и желательно сделать полновесный демон за которым бы следила система управления службами (демонами) а-ля `systemd, supervisor` или что там у вас. Таким образом упавший скрипт будет поднят автоматически.

Comment: set_time_limit(0); помогло